How can I read PySpark code from S3 buckets?
I have my Apache Livy setup and PySpark setup in AWS and I have kept my PySpark code in S3 bucket.
Here is my code to submit via Livy:
import requests
import json


livy_url_battches = "http://56.43.345.87:8998/batches"


payload = {
    "file": "s3a://abctesting/sparkcode.py",
    "className": "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi",


"conf": {
    "spark.executor.memory": "3g",
    "spark.driver.memory": "1g",
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key": "myAccessKey",
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key": "mySecreteKey",
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint": "s3.amazonaws.com",  
    "spark.jars": "https://abctesting.s3.amazonaws.com/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.262.jar,https://abctesting.s3.amazonaws.com/hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar",

},
}




headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
try:

    response = requests.post(livy_url_battches, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))

    response.status_code == 201
    print("Batch job submitted successfully.")
    print(response.json())

except Exception as error:
    print("Error ===",error)

After this I am getting this error:
24/09/03 10:59:32 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using pySpark-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1831)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.downloadFile(DependencyUtils.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$8(SparkSubmit.scala:404)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:404)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:964)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
    ... 19 more

I think hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar and aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.262.jar these jar files are not being read by the spark but I am providing it in Livy palylod.
What can be done to solve this issue?

try "spark.packages": "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4" instead of spark.jars. I never had to specify aws-java-sdk-bundle, but if needed add that too.

@Kashyap still getting same error

Problem is exactly as you pointed out "jars are not part of Spark's classpath". Solution depends on how your env is set up. E.g. if it's a Databricks cluster then add a cluster library dependency. If it's spark-submit then use --packages param, or provide config in config file. Never worked with Livy so...
